# How to make a li element not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am quite new to html, css, and javascript and I was wondering if there is a way to make a `<li>` element not clickable. Basically I want to have one active element and the have the other elements disabled and not clickable.

[image]

Right now when I click on some other `<li>` the active moves to that element and I can't figure out how to leave it on the first element.

Comment: post some code of the dropdown

Comment: The default behaviour for a click on an li element is to do nothing, so it seems to me that you could solve your problem by simply not binding a "click" handler with JS... Please post the relevant html and JavaScript so that we can advise which part of your existing code to change.

Comment: Your question is very confusing, really.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to post code of the dropdown as it is impossible to help you further without knowing how the `<li>` tags are being triggered.

Here is a jQuery example that shows a very simple list item menu.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/r3368/)</kbd>

I added two ways to stop the `<li>` elements from being clickable: simple boolean switch, and using jQuery's `.off()` method.

**HTML:**

```
Some List Items:<br>
<ul>
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li class="active">Second Item</li>
    <li>Third Item</li>
    <li>Fourth Item</li>
</ul>
<input id="mybutt" type="button" value="Disallow First Click" />
```

**jQuery/javascript:**

```
var ok2change=1;

$('body').on('click', 'li', function() {
    if (ok2change==1){
        $('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        ok2change=0;
    }
});

$('#mybutt').click(function() {
    $('body').off('click', 'li');
    $(this).val('First click disallowed also');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some css class to the "active" li element and change the selector of the attached handler, so that it attaches only to it:

```
$("li.someCssClass").click(function() {
  // ...
});
```

here only li elenements having "someCssClass" will react on the click, others will not.

Comment: or off() function in jquery

Comment: Really? jQuery for this? `I am quite new to html, css, javascript`, he says. You should explain it better.

Comment: See the tags: jquery mentioned.

Comment: @Diéssica Personally, I started learning jQuery and javascript at the same time and found jQuery tons easier. (And **much** less typing, which helped a lot.)

Comment: Yep, @gibberish, but this can be "vicious". I also like jQuery, but sometimes it's unnecessary. It can be simple with JavaScript too, don't you think? :)

Comment: @gibberish - jQuery isn't easier than JavaScript, jQuery _is_ JavaScript. It's "just" a collection of JS functions, it's not magic. (Having said that, I use and recommend jQuery...)

Comment: "no jquery" would mean you should be immediately aware of the differences between javascript and dom implementations across browsers, which is already a complexity.